# java "import java.util.*" compilation failure on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: java

I wrote a very simple program on java stack operation. I am using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment with OS X 10.9.1. I have tried JDK build 1.7.0_13-b20 and build 1.7.0_51-b13, both do not work for me. I just wanted to test the java Stack class. I do not have a private stack implementation. And the $CLASSPATH environment variable is set to empty.

I tested the same program on Windows (Win 8.1) with JDK 1.7.0_25. It worked fine.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyStackTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<Integer> mys = new Stack<Integer>();
        mys.push(5);

        while ( ! mys.empty() ) {
            System.out.println(mys.peek());
            mys.pop();
        }
    }
 }
```

However, while compiling using javac 1.7.0_13, I got "cannot find symbol" error:

```
$ javac MyStackTest.java  -Xlint
MyStackTest.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        while ( ! mys.empty() ) {
                 ^
  symbol:   method empty()
  location: variable mys of type Stack<Integer>
1 error
```

I found that if I change the import statement to

```
import java.util.Stack
```

the program compiles fine. Why did "import java.util.*" cause the problem? How can I tell which class in java.util.* cause the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It compiles fine for me with 1.7.0_51-b13.

Comment: Have you defined your own `Stack` class?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between the two imports (with regard to what one can do with the imported classes), but I can't remember what it is.  (And it doesn't seem like it would apply in this case.)

Comment: @arshajii I copied the above source and it compiled and ran fine.  Then I created my own Stack class and received similar compiler errors.  Then I changed the import statement to `import java.util.Stack`, and it again compiled and ran fine.  I used 1.7.0_25.

Comment: Why did it not complain about mys.push?

Comment: @rgettman - That might be the difference I was thinking of.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe the custom `Stack` class has its own `push`, `peek`,  and `pop` methods, but not an `empty` method.

Comment: @rgettman - Yep, that's totally consistent.  But of course the OP has not admitted to having his own Stack class yet.

Comment: @rgettman That's interesting, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @yuyang Without a custom `Stack` class, this code compiles and runs fine, regardless of which import statement is used.  Are you sure you don't have your own `Stack` class, even some old `Stack.class` file somewhere in your classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a `Stack` implementation in the same package as your `MyStackTest` class (in this case the default package name). Comment out everything after `new Stack` and print out the class type. If it's not `java.util.Stack` then you've found your answer.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyStackTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<Integer> mys = new Stack<Integer>();

        System.out.println(mys.getClass());
    }
}
```

Another possibility is that you have non-UTF8 characters in `mys.empty()`. Try deleting that line and hand type it again.

Answer (score 0):

when you run the compiler for execution from the command line (DOS I guess...) it has to be specified the complete route to every class involved in the java file, or every class needs to be in the same package. That's why when you call javac it can't find the Stack class.

Comment: The title indicates Mac OS X 10.9.1, not DOS.